# 2022 wasm blazor.webassembly.js not found .net5 to .net6 upgrade

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to upgrade from a Blazor WASM .net5 project to .net6.  I change the  to net6.0 on all the projects.  All compiles well, but I get a 404 error on loading blazor.webassembly.js

When I search for it from explorer I find it at: examgenerator\bin\Debug\net6.0\wwwroot_framework

while the request URL is: https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js

What am I missing?

Comment: I had this issue upgrading from 3.1 to 6 and I haven't solved it directly, I created a new project with net 6 and included all the files. I hope you have more patience than I had, so it will help others.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  Worked well, but a pain.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite easy to miss, but you need to ensure that your Client project is declared like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--The rest of your code here-->
</Project>
```

Notice that `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` was changed to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly`.

---

It's also important to have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` up to date.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
```

A diff tool like [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org) is really helpful when looking for differences like this.

**Note:**
There's a good chance that you'll run into some other issue (most likely hot reload related) while making such an upgrade. Until Microsoft comes up with a super clean solution to this, your best bet is to create a new .NET 6 project and move your code files there. This might of course be a frustrating option, but it's **will** save you so much more time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if you have updated all your Nuget packages. Had this issue as well and had it resolved when I updated all my packages, particularly the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` package.

Comment: Good thought, but that was one of the first things I did in converting.