# Blazor Webassembly App unable to connect Web Socket after upgrade to .NET 6

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have upgraded a `Blazor WASM` project `.net 5` project to `.net 6`.

The `Blazor.Server` project is set as the startup WebApi project, with a `Blazor.Client` containing all the blazor code.

This was working fine, however after the upgrade when I try to run the project I get the following error in the cmd output;

> Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A56020%2Fdevtools%2Fbrowser%2F6d6a929b-4e01-4e15-8e7c-e4e19e0bb5c4 - - - 404 0 - 0.9436

On the `Blazor.Server` project I have;

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server 6.0.3
```

then (again in the Server side project) in the `Program.cs` I have added;

```
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpErrorHandlerMiddleware();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

//app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseCors(AllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});

app.UseRequestLocalization("en-GB");

app.Run();
```

In the `Blazor.Client` WASM app I have;

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 6.0.3
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer 6.0.3
```

Then in the `Program.cs` here I have;

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

var services = builder.Services;

services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
services.AddAuthorizationCore();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, JwtAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

services.AddTransient<TimerService>();
services.AddTransient<MapperService>();
services.AddTransient<GenericMapperService>();

services.AddLogging(b => b
   .AddBrowserConsole()
   .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error)
);

services.AddBlazorise(options =>
{
    // options.ChangeTextOnKeyPress = true; // optional
})
.AddBootstrapProviders()
.AddFontAwesomeIcons();

builder.Services.AddHttpClientInterceptor();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Can anyone help here please? I assume that VS and the installed Webassembly packages know how to copy across the blazor runtime? Or is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues upgrading projects with Blazor Wasm and I am not the only 1, so far the best work around is to recreate the project in .net6. Not sure if this is your case.

See this [2022 wasm blazor.webassembly.js not found .net5 to .net6 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393993/2022-wasm-blazor-webassembly-js-not-found-net5-to-net6-upgrade#comment124435140_70393993)

Hopefully, a better solution exists and will eventually be found. If you're patient enough, this thread might find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when I create a new templated project (in .net6) it create all in a single project now. I'd like to maintain the separation between the API side and the WASM side. I think this will then just leave me in the same situation I am currently?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone the work around I ended up implementing was to just run the 2x project separately;

1. Set multiple startup projects an set the `Blazor.Client` and `Blazor.Api` to startup.

In the `Blazor.Server` project

2. Remove the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server 6.0.3`
3. From the `Program.cs` remove;

`app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();`
and
`endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");`

4. Change the `launchSettings.json` to remove the `inspectUri` settings.

In the `Blazor.Client` project;

5.ammend the `HttpClient` base Uri to point to the API project. For example;

`builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/") });`

and make sure that both projects are running on separate ports. All ran smoothly after this.

Not an ideal solution as it mean two different services running, but a quick workaround.