# How to convert blazor web Assembly from .net framework 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtSre.jpg)I have blazor web Assembly project .net 5.0. I have changed Target .Net Framework 6.0 in visual studio 2022. But I can not application and its shows an console error message.
Please check below screeshot and advise how to resolve thus

```
blazor web assembly console error .net 6.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiTeC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been there and I have seen others having same issue.

The post here has some steps you can try and see if it works

[2022 wasm blazor.webassembly.js not found .net5 to .net6 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393993/2022-wasm-blazor-webassembly-js-not-found-net5-to-net6-upgrade?noredirect=1#comment124535395_70393993)

If not, your best bet is to create a new project with .net6. Kind of a pain though.

Comment: I have check above link and now I am getting another issue when i compile please check attached edited image

Comment: @Ismail Perhaps this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374907/the-visual-studio-2022-error-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-additional-informa?rq=1  Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767169/visual-studio-2017-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-chrome

Comment: Thanks ,it works fine now but I am getting exception error in console for "blazor.webassembly.js".Please check updated attached screenshot for your reference and advise how to resolve this issues...

Comment: @Ismail Sorry, I have no idea. All I can say is, if you create a new project in .net6 and reimport the code files from the other one, it will work. As for fixing the upgrade, I have yet to know a case that worked.